# Validate presence in this belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, belongs-to

I have products and brands
products model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :brand_id, :title
  belongs_to :brand

  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :brand, :presence => {:message => 'The brand no exists'}
end
```

and the brands model

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :name
  validates :name, :presence => true

  has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

I want to validate if exist a product with a name in this brand.
I mean I could have 2 products with the same name in different brands but not in the same brand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `uniqueness` validation with a `scope`:

```
validates :name, :uniqueness => { :scope => :brand_id }
```

Note that you have to specify `:brand_id` instead of `:brand`, because the validation can't be made on the relation.

If you don't know it, I suggest you to read the [Active Record Validations and Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#uniqueness) guide.

NB: the syntax `{:foo => 'bar'}` is replaced (since Ruby 1.9.2) with `{foo: 'bar'}`.